# How to access your systems media player when coding a VSCode extension, through a nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, vscode-extensions

I am using the library `play-sound`. I have tried 2 different statements, which yield different results, neither successful. When I use

`const player = require('play-sound')({player: "mplayer"})`
The extension works with no error codes, but no audio is played.

`const player = require('play-sound')()` The extension still runs, but I get the error code

`Could not play sound: Error: Couldn't find a suitable audio player`. Likewise, no sound is produced.

How can I access my systems audio while coding a vscode extension?

PS: Here is the code I run to play the audio

```
player.play('noise.mp3', (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(`Could not play sound: ${err}`);
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried any other player to run the sound?

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
const player = require('play-sound')(opts = {});

// $ mplayer foo.mp3 
player.play('foo.mp3', function(err){
  if (err) throw err
})
```

I have just tried this on my system it plays, just make sure the path for the file is correct and it is `mp3`.